# awk and if condition does not work properly

Tags: awk

input example (columns delimited with `:`)

```
US233541:us33541:User Name1:user1@host.com:CN=User 1,OU=Users,OU=AAA,OU=Customer,DC=Domain,DC=com:132572652198323884
US233555:us33555:User Name2:user2@host.com:CN=User 2,OU=Users,OU=BBB,OU=Customer,DC=Domain,DC=com:
US233590:us33590:User Name3:user3@host.com:CN=User 3,OU=Users,OU=AAA,OU=Customer,DC=Domain,DC=com:132572489898481346
US233599:us33599:User Name4:user4@host.com:CN=User 4,OU=Users,OU=BBB,OU=Customer,DC=Domain,DC=com:0
US233500:us33500:User Name5:user5@host.com:CN=User 5,OU=Users,OU=CCC,OU=Customer,DC=Domain,DC=com:X
```

Expected output is TAB delimited fields where last column is time in AD date format converted to human readable date. Of course I need to ignore any none-convertible strings from this last column.

What I have tried does not work, looks like if condition does not work well for me - all are use "else" and set "n/a"

```
$ awk -F: '$2!=""{gsub(/CN=.+OU=Users,/," ");gsub(/,OU=.+$/," ");if($6~/^[0-9]+$/ || $6>0) {d=strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y",($6/10000000)-11644473600)} else {d="n/a"}}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,d}' OFS=$'\t' input
US233541        us33541 User Name1      user1@host.com   OU=AAA         n/a
US233555        us33555 User Name2      user2@host.com   OU=BBB         n/a
US233590        us33590 User Name3      user3@host.com   OU=AAA         n/a
US233599        us33599 User Name4      user4@host.com   OU=BBB         n/a
US233500        us33500 User Name5      user5@host.com   OU=CCC         n/a
```

Comment: The problem here comes from `gsub(/,OU=.+$/," ")`. For example, `.+$` matches to `,OU=Customer,DC=Domain,DC=com:132572652198323884` and removes it. That is, the 6th field is gone before you want to do something about it! As an experiment, try running `awk -F: '$2!=""{gsub(/CN=.+OU=Users,/," ");gsub(/,OU=.+$/," ");print $0}' OFS=$'\t' input`

Comment: Also, `$6~/^[0-9]+$/ || $6>0` seems wrong, you may want `&&` instead.

Answer (score 4):

since you have difficulty for the last field, here is a working version

```
$ awk -F: '{print ($NF~/^[0-9]+$/ && $NF>0)?strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y",$NF/10000000-11644473600):"n/a"}' file

Mon Feb 08 08:40:19 EST 2021
n/a
Mon Feb 08 04:09:49 EST 2021
n/a
n/a
```

Before this gets too many votes, the real reason is the greedy `gsub` as mentioned in the comments and other answer.  Since, I just looked at the last field I missed the main issue.  The other problem was `||` vs `&&` use but it's secondary.  Note also that `$NF>0` can be replace with `$NF` since first condition ensures it's an integer.

Answer (score 4):

It is thhe gsub functions that are causing the issue, as well as the if statement containing || as opposed to &&. Reworking your solution using both ":" and "," as field delimiters and to negate the need to use gsub:

```
awk -F [\:\,] '$2!=""{if($NF~/^[0-9]+$/ && $NF>0) {d=strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y",($NF/10000000)-11644473600)} else {d="n/a"}} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$7,d}' OFS=$'\t' file
```

Comment: is the a way to omit comma as a separator on -F? I am afraid if someone has , on Real Name attribute value it can stop working...

Comment: If you are using GNU awk, you can split the 5th field based on regular expressions using gensub

Answer (score 0):

thx for all hints here what is working now

```
awk -F$'\t' '$2!=""{{gsub(/CN=.+OU=Users,/,"",$5);gsub(/,OU=.+$/,"",$5);if($6~/^[0-9]+$/&&$6>0) {d=strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y",($6/10000000)-11644473600)} else {d="n/a"}}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,d}}' OFS=$'\t'
```